# Numpy flatten a nested array using concatenate

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array with subarrays of different shapes. I was trying to use an iterator to flatten them into a 1D array. Below is the code:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([np.random.rand(1,2),np.random.rand(2,2),np.random.rand(1,4)],dtype=object)
b=np.concatenate(x.ravel for x in a)
```

This returns an error:

```
TypeError: The first input argument needs to be a sequence
```

I am not quite sure what I am doing incorrectly. It works fine when I create a for loop with the same logic and keep concatenating my array recursively. Any help appreciated.

The goal is to flatten the array into a 1D array. (Note that hstack doesn't work because the arrays are of different shapes. flatten doesn't work because it is already a 1D array (of arrays).)

Comment: b=np.concatenate([x.ravel() for x in a])

Answer (score 0):

```
b=np.concatenate([x.ravel() for x in a])
print(b)
array([0.0928126 , 0.26396728, 0.37416516, 0.86079876, 0.3070049 ,
       0.86714361, 0.67955231, 0.11715076, 0.34659847, 0.17392114])
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, 
**[including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) 
really helps to improve the quality of your post**. Remember that you are 
answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might 
not know the reasons for your code suggestion.